# How to properly implement scipy.integrate.Radau?

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

(I'll apreciate even a link to an example, so far I haven't found any.)

I am trying to use [Radau](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.Radau.html) from scipy.integrate to solve second order differential equation. For now I am trying just a simple example, so that I can uderstand how it works (unsuccessfully so far).

Let's say that I have following equation:

d^2y/dt^2 = C,

which means that y = (C*t^2)/2 + B*t.

Let's say, for example, y(1) = 1 and C = 2. Let's say that I want to find value of y for t = 10.

This is my code:

```
from scipy.integrate import Radau
import numpy as np

C = 2.0
y = np.zeros(2)

def fun(t, y):
  #y[0] = C*t
  y[1] = C
  return y

t0 = 1.0
y0 = np.array([1., 1.])
t_bound = 10.0

eq = Radau(fun, t0, y0, t_bound)
print(eq.n)

while(True):
  print(eq.t)
  print(eq.y)
  print(eq.status)
  if eq.status == 'finished':
    break
  eq.step()
```

Outputs is wrong. (If I uncomment that one commented line in `fun` definition, it also gives wrong answer. But I think that I shouldn't even have to tell solver that, right? I don't know this value usually.)

I think my biggest problem is that I am not really sure what should be passed as `fun`. Documentation says it should be right-hand side of the system, so I thought that first derivation should be in y[0], second derivation in y[1] etc.

What am I doing wrong? How should this be implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atm you are solving

```
y0' = y0,  y0(1)=1
y1' = 2,   y1(1)=1
```

which has the solution `y0(t)=exp(t-1)` and `y1(t)=2*t-1` which is certainly not what you want. You want the first order system

```
y0' = y1
y1' = C
```

so that you need

```
def fun(t,y): return [y[1], C]
```

Then the solution is `y1(t)=C*t+B=2*t-1` and `y0(t)=0.5*C*t^2+B*t+A=t^2-t+1` and the integration ends correctly with `eq.y = [91. 19.]`.

Comment: Oh, right, I made a mistake even in math... I am going to try it out right away.

Comment: The python version of  Radau says that it is based on "Implicit Runge-Kutta method of Radau IIA family of order 5". This method has the ability to solve problems with a mass matrix but I can't see how this is implemented. I assume that the **extraneous is used somehow, but it is not documented. Any ideas?.

Comment: @GrahamG : Yes, it is possible to write the implicit step equations with a mass matrix on the derivatives side, the inversion of that can be replaced/combined with the inversion of the system Jacobian in the Newton-like iteration to solve the step equation. I have never seen this or DAE related techniques in practice or announced for any of the scipy solvers.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann: Many thanks for your response. The DAE problem is essentially defined by: M*du/dt=f(u). In order to solve this in python I have tried changing the problem to, (A) du/dt = pinv_M@f(u)   # cannot use inv_M as M is singular and (B) du/dt = np.linalg.lstsq(M,f(u),rcond=None)[0]. But both give the wrong answer. The same problem using Radau in R, and specifying the mass matrix M, gives the correct answer.

Comment: @GrahamG : Using `pinv` you are setting the algebraic components of the right side to zero, thus leaving them constant. This is of course then a different system. Converting a DAE problem into an ODE system is the main motivation of the index theories of DAE, after the obvious index-1 situations they become rapidly non-trivial.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann: This is an index-1 DAE problem and it seem like I have hit a brick wall in python. I have also found the python package pyradau13 which has a Radau solver, but I cannot get working in Anaconda under Windows 10. Thanks for all your comments.

Comment: @GrahamG : You would need to convert it into an ODE system and manually find a consistent initial state. Or use, if it exists, a python wrapper to open-modelica or similar, or a wrapper to a more complete DE library like sundials or julia-lang differentialequations.jl

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann: Thanks. I will look into your suggestions.